# Meta tag не обновляется при переходе по ссылкам на страницы одного контроллера

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1) в контроллере определяю переменную `@info = Info.find_by slug: params[:id]`

2) В хелпере определяю два метода:

```
  def title_for_info
    if @info.present?
      @info.title
    else
      "Текст"
    end
  end

  def description_for_info
    # @info = Info.find_by slug: params[:id]
    if @info.present?
      @info.description
    else
      "Текст"
    end
  end
```

3) В соответствующем лейауте прописываю:

```
%meta{:content => "#{description_for_info}",:name => "description"}/
%title= title_for_info
```

Есть страница со списком ссылок, при переходе по любой получается следующее: title загружается всегда корректно, а вот description всегда уходит по ветке в "Текст". Если же на этой изначальной странице ссылку скопировать и открыть в новой вкладке( или тупо обновить страницу), то description грузится корректно. Так же все корректно отрабатывает если перед мета-тегом тупо вывести `= @info.description`

Почему наблюдается такое поведение и что с этим делать?

**Update**
 В общем и целом это особенности работы [Turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463978/rails-4-and-turbolinks-meta-tags-not-changing), пока думаю как обойтись без гемов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В моем случае помогло добавить к ссылкам на начальной странице `:target => '_self'`